# Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and Control.Dispatcher.Invoke() order execution is confusing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF, and I was confused about the order of execution `Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` and `Control.Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

I will show an example of code below

```
backgroundThread = new Thread(BackgroundThread);
backgroundThread.Start();
public void BackgroundThread()
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
      WriteLog("Run command 1");
    }));

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
      WriteLog("Run command 2");
    }));
}
```

I expect the "Command 1" will be run and finished before "command 2", but sometimes It seems the "Command 2" run before "Command 1". I have researched much on internet and MSDN document, but I don't understand why this happen.

Someone please tell me the rule of these functions exactly?

Many thanks!

T&T

Comment: Not with this code.  Just log the value of Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedId.  You'll probably see the that the code isn't actually running on the UI thread.  Wrong dispatcher.

Comment: Thank you, Hans Passant!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BeginInvoke` calls the `Action` you pass to it asynchronously on the thread that is associated with the `Dispatcher` while `Invoke` calls that action synchronously.

In other words, `Invoke` immediately executes what ever `Action` you pass to it while `BeginInvoke` puts the action you pass to it on the `Dispatcher` queue which is like a list of the things the `Dispatcher` is going to do but with no guarantee when that is going to happen or as soon as the dispatcher has finished doing the other things waiting on that queue.

So sometimes the `Dispatcher` might be busy doing something else and puts the action you pass to `BeginInvoke` on  the queue's end until it can execute it, and then it executes whatever action you pass to `Invoke` immediately and that is the reason for the order differences.

Comment: Thank You, Sniffer, but on MSDN said that both Invoke() and BeginInvoke() add their message in the same Dispatcher. So The "Command 1" will be process fisrt ^^

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.aspx

Comment: well, I suspected about default priority of Invoke() and BeginInvoke() fucntions caused this case, but I don't sure because I don't see any document that mention this yet! Do you have any doc about this? Many Thanks!

Comment: @TTGroup you are correct, they are both added to the dispatcher but with one main difference, the call to `BeginInvoke` returns immediately even if the action hasn't been called yet while the call to `Invoke` doesn't return until the the action has been called and finished.

Comment: @TTGroup i am sorry i was mistaken, they are both called with Normal priority, there is no documentation on the internal implementation of those two methods but you can use .NET Reflector to get an idea what is going on on the inside.

Comment: @TTGroup I have taken a look at the implementation using reflector and it is a complex one especially with the comments but from what i saw it looks like `Invoke` doesn't put the action on the queue but rather tries to execute it immediately unless some synchronization issues arise which forces Dispatcher to put the action on the queue. On the other hand, the default behavior for `BeginInvoke` is to put the action on the queue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I had enough information from your answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Someone please tell me the rule of these functions exactly

Following is the diffrence

```
Dispatcher.Invoke: Executes the specified delegate synchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke: Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with..
```

and now your understanding

> I expect the "Command 1" will be run and finished before "command 2",
>   but sometimes It seems the "Command 2" run before "Command 1"

As your first call is Asynchronous so it may finish before or after your second call (which is synchronous).

Comment: Thank you!
But are you sure Dispatcher.Invoke will executed on the same thread?
I know that the background thread can not access UI components, so I still think that both Invoke() and BeginInvoke() are executed on the same thread of Control's Dispatcher as MSDN mentioned!

Comment: @Ehasan Ullah: Your edited answer still exist the issue about "same thread" as my above comment mentioned! Thanks anyway ^^

Comment: @TTGroup yes it will execute on the thread that dispatcher is assoicated with and in synchronous manner

Answer (score 2):

well, i think sniffer's answer is pretty clear enough. basiclly you get almost all the idea here, the last thing may need your orgnize those concepts.

1, the **Invoke** here you called will switch the current main thread execution to the UI thread **synchronously**, of course, if it's a loooong running, will block the main thread until your invoke code completion;
2, The difference of **BeginInvoke** is that this switch happens **asynchronously**, wouldn't affect the main thread.

and i assume you already understand why the output sequence

Comment: I got it! Thank You, Ethan Wang :)

Answer (score 1):

> I expect the "Command 1" will be run and finished before "command 2",
>   but sometimes It seems the "Command 2" run before "Command 1".

Your assumption is wrong because `Control.BeginInvoke` runs asynchronously while the `Control.Invoke` runs synchronously.

If you want to make sure command 1 runs before command 2, run command 1 using `Invoke`.

When you use `BeginInvoke` you are not getting the `order guarantee` because it's upto Dispatcher when it's going to execute it.

Comment: Thank you! But there are some reasons, so I can not use both are BeginInvoke() or Invoke()!

Comment: @TTGroup You can use both but you should keep in mind their properties and how they are going to effect the output and it's order